# Can you calculate a standard error from confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, incidence-rate-ratio

Specifically, can I calculate a standard error from an incidence rate with known confidence intervals but no population size data?

Comment: Can you expand on why you think you cannot do this? Usually the confidence limits have been calculated using the standard error, possibly on a transformed scale.

Comment: I'm assuming you can, I just don't know how. The CIs have been reported in a paper, but without other info. I'm trying to work backwards to calculate the SE. Although, I think the following solves it  (upper CI - Lower CI)/3.92.    I thought this was only for a difference in means but it seems to work on other data that I do have numbers for.

Comment: Looks good to me. They might have used the t-test rather than the normal  but that would lead to a larger number than 3.92 and hence a smaller se so you are being conservative.

Comment: Do not forget to work on the correct scale though. For instance you may have to log transform everything first.